# Build own AppleScript numerical error handling

Tags: json, macos, applescript

I'm wanting to build an app for validating projects using custom error numbers I've defined similar to:

```
try
    ## do something
on error number -2700
    display dialog "Foobar"
end try
```

with the help of [JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSONHelper.html) defining the list as:

```
tell application "JSON Helper"
    set myJSON to make JSON from {-1232:"missing definition", -123231:"foo", -1232314:"bar" }
    return myJSON
end tell
```

however I do not see a way to do this after referencing:

- [Error Numbers and Error Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html)
- [Working with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html)

other then using a bloated conditional like:

```
try
    open for access file "MyFolder:AddressData" with write permission
on error msg number n from f to t partial result p
    if n = -49 then -- File already open error
        display dialog "I'm sorry but the file is already open."
    else
        error msg number n from f to t partial result p
    end if
end try
```

After researching I was unable to populate anything other than "[What techniques work to handle errors in AppleScript so I can place a dialog?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85682/what-techniques-work-to-handle-errors-in-applescript-so-i-can-place-a-dialog)" so is there a way in AppleScript I can write error handling similar to Error Numbers and Error Messages documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible with a `property list items`.

This script put a record in a new `property list item`

Use the error number as string to get the value in the `property list items`

```
set myRecord to {|-1232|:"missing definition", |-123231|:"foo", |-1232314|:"bar", |-49|:"I'm sorry but the file is already open.", |-43|:"This file wasn’t found."}
tell application "System Events" to set myPlist to make new property list item with properties {kind:record, value:myRecord}

try
    open for access file "MyFolder:AddressData" with write permission
on error number n
    tell application "System Events" to set r to value of first property list item of myPlist whose its name is (n as text)
    display alert r
end try
```

---

Question of **JMichaelTX**

Here's a script to save a `property list items` to a **PLIST** file (In the  **Preferences** folder in this example).

```
set plistPath to (path to preferences folder as string) & "errorsMsgs.plist"
tell application "System Events"
    set myPlist to make new property list item with properties {kind:record, value:myRecord}
    make new property list file with properties {contents:myPlist, name:plistPath}
end tell
```