# OS X - JavaScript for Automation - How to create and store variable for future use

Tags: macos, javascript-automation

I am creating a small program that will help automate the initialization of a virtual environment and startup of a Django server. I would like to share this program with others.

I am looking for a way to create a variable (location of a folder) through the use of an open file browser and store that variable so that the user does not have to enter it in the future.

How can I store new information in my program for future use? I investigated the use of the plist file but cant find any documentation anywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know you are using JXA, but this AppleScript shows how to use plist.  You should be able to translate it to JXA:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35734698/build-own-applescript-numerical-error-handling/35749787#35749787

Answer (score 1):

You can persistently store simple values in the user's preferences by using the NSUserDefaults class from Cocoa.

The following script asks the user to choose a folder location the first time it is run and then stores the chosen location in the user's defaults. When the script is run again, it returns the stored location without prompting the user. (Change the `suiteName` and `locationKey` values as appropriate for your script.)

```
var currentApp = Application.currentApplication()
currentApp.includeStandardAdditions = true

var suiteName = "your.suite.name";
var locationKey = "your.prefs.key";

var $ud = $.NSUserDefaults.alloc.initWithSuiteName(suiteName);
var $location = $ud.stringForKey(locationKey);
var locationPath = $location.isNil() ? currentApp.chooseFolder() : Path($location.js);
$ud.setObjectForKey($(locationPath.toString()), locationKey);

locationPath
```

Note that you can also interact with the user's preferences using the `defaults` command-line tool, e.g.:

```
defaults read your.suite.name your.prefs.key
defaults delete your.suite.name your.prefs.key
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggested using plist above, but I just ran across this great tool:
[JSON Helper](http://www.mousedown.net/mouseware/JSONHelper.html)

It is a app that supports scripting.  The examples are shown in AppleScript, but should be easily translated to JXA.

> JSON Helper is an agent (or scriptable background application) which
> allows you to do useful things with JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)
> directly from AppleScript. JSON Helper has no interface, and runs in
> the background waiting for AppleScripts [or JXA] to ask it to do something,
> just like Apple's own System Events does.
>
> JSON Helper contains a
> number of commands that help you parse JSON into regular AppleScript
> lists and records, and convert AppleScript list and records back into
> valid JSON. In addition JSON Helper contains some convenience commands
> to allow you to communicate easily with web based APIs.